# Simplifying $\sum 2^k \tan(2^k x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Simplify $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{2^k}\tan ({2^k}x)}$ which $k \in \{ 0,1,...,n + 1\} ,{2^k}x \notin \{ 0,\frac{\pi }{2}\}$

Comment: P.S.: What does segma mean? I'm sure you didn't mean [this](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=segma). But beware of inuendos. ;P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint:** $\ln(\cos(x))'=\tan(x)$ and [Recursion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/prove-cos-a-cdot-cos-2a-cdot-cos-22a-cdot-cos-23a-cos-2n-1).

**Alternative route:** Use the identity $\cot(x) - 2\cot(2x)=\tan(x)$ and telescoping.