# Can $\prod\limits_{k=0}^n \left( 2 \cosh(2^kx)-1 \right)$ be simplified?

Tags: calculus, products

Do you know if the product $\prod\limits_{k=0}^n \left( 2 \cosh(2^kx)-1 \right)$ can be simplified?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align*}
2\cosh(2^k x)-1 &= \exp(2^k x) - 1 + \exp(-2^k x) \\
&= \exp(-2^k x) \frac{\exp(3\cdot2^k x) + 1}{\exp(2^k x) + 1}\\
&= \frac{\cosh(\frac{3}{2}2^k x)}{\cosh(\frac{1}{2}2^k x)}.
\end{align*}$$

Then we have

$$\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=0}^{n} \left(2\cosh(2^k x)-1 \right)
&= \prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\cosh(\frac{3}{2}2^k x)}{\cosh(\frac{1}{2}2^k x)} \\
&= \frac{\sinh(\frac{3}{2}2^{n+1} x)/\sinh(\frac{3}{2} x)}{\sinh(\frac{1}{2}2^{n+1} x)/\sinh(\frac{1}{2} x)} \\
&= \frac{2\cosh(2^{n+1}x)+1}{2\cosh x+1}.
 \end{align*}$$

Sorry for this unfriendly solution. I typed these formulas with my iPad3 and this drove me nearly mad.

Answer (score 1):

$b^2+b^{-2}+1=(b+b^{-1})^2-1=(b+b^{-1}+1)(b+b^{-1}-1)$

Putting $b=e^{2^{k+1}x}, 2 \cosh(2^{k+1}x)+1=(2 \cosh(2^kx)+1)(2 \cosh(2^kx)-1)$

Putting $k=0,1,\cdots ,n$

$2 \cosh(2^{0+1}x)+1=(2 \cosh(2^0x)+1)(2 \cosh(2^0x)-1)$

$2 \cosh(2^{1+1}x)+1=(2 \cosh(2^1x)+1)(2 \cosh(2^1x)-1)$

...

$2 \cosh(2^{n+1}x)+1=(2 \cosh(2^nx)+1)(2 \cosh(2^nx)-1)$

On multiplication,

$2 \cosh(2^{n+1}x)+1=(2 \cosh x+1)\prod_{0\le k\le n}(2 \cosh(2^kx)-1)$

---

Alternatively,

$ 2 \cosh(2^kx)-1=e^{2^kx}+e^{-2^kx}-1$

Putting $a=e^x,$

for $k=0,\frac{a^2-a+1}a=\frac{a^3+1}{a(a+1)}$

for $k=1,\frac{a^4-a^2+1}{a^2}=\frac{(a^3)^2+1}{a^2(a^2+1)}$

for $k=3,\frac{a^8-a^4+1}{a^4}=\frac{(a^3)^4+1}{a^4(a^4+1)}$

for $k=n,\frac{a^{2^{n+1}}-a^{2^n}+1}{a^{2^n}}=\frac{(a^3)^{2^n}+1}{a^{2^n}(a^{2^n}+1)}$

On multiplication the RHS becomes, $$\frac{(a^3+1)((a^3)^2+1)((a^3)^4+1)\cdots((a^3)^{2^n}+1)}{a^{1+2+3+\cdots+2^n}(a+1)(a^2+1)(a^4+1)\cdots (a^{2^n}+1)}$$

$$=\frac{(a^3-1)(a^3+1)((a^3)^2+1)((a^3)^4+1)\cdots((a^3)^{2^n}+1)}{(a-1)(a+1)(a^2+1)(a^4+1)\cdots (a^{2^n}+1)}\cdot\frac{(a-1)}{(a^3-1)a^{1+2+3+\cdots+2^n}}$$

$$=\frac{((a^3)^{2^{n+1}}-1)(a-1)}{(a^{2^{n+1}}-1)(a^3-1)}\cdot\frac1{(a^{2^{n+1}-1})}$$ as $(b-1)(b+1)(b^2+1)(b^4+1)\cdots(b^{2^m}+1)=(b^2-1)(b^2+1)(b^4+1)\cdots(b^{2^m}+1)=(b^4-1)(b^4+1)\cdots(b^{2^m}+1)=b^{2^{m+1}}-1$

$$=\frac{(a^2)^{2^{n+1}}+a^{2^{n+1}}+1}{(a^{2^{n+1}-1})(a^2+a+1)}$$ (applying $\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}=x^2+x+1$)

$$=\frac{a^{2^{n+1}}+a^{-2^{n+1}}+1}{(a+a^{-1}+1)}$$ (Dividing the numerator & the denominator by $a^{2^{n+1}}$)

$$=\frac{2\cosh(2^{n+1}x)+1}{2\cosh x+1}$$ (Replacing $a$ with $e^x$ )