# Prove the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, proof-writing

$$\cos \frac{x}{2} \cdot \cos \frac{x}{4} \cdot \cos \frac{x}{8} = \frac{\sin x}{ 8\sin \frac{x}{8}}$$

Conjecture a generalization of this result and prove its correctness by induction.

Ps: I have tried using identities, but I keep running on a loop. I wanted to use identities first to have an idea of what I have to do to generalize.
Any ideas will be gladly appreciate it!

Comment: An equivalent question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/8439/1242

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\cos \frac{x}{2} \cdot \cos \frac{x}{4} \cdot \cos \frac{x}{8}\times 8 \sin \frac{x}{8}=4\cos \frac{x}{2} \cdot \cos \frac{x}{4} \cdot\sin\frac{x}{4}=2\cos \frac{x}{2} \cdot\sin \frac{x}{2} =\sin x$$

The generalization is
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\cos \frac{x}{2^k} =\frac{\sin x}{2^n\sin \frac{x}{2^n} }$$

Comment: It seems that you are busy these days as I but +1 makes you free. ;-)

Comment: @BabakS. What do you think of a person who teaches 24 hours a week and probably this requires much time to prepare the course of each session   all this makes me very busy but Luckily I found in this site a lovely friend who makes me free :)

Comment: The same story is for me, but I do 23 hours a week ;-) Great job Sami. :-)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A$$

Put $\displaystyle A=\frac x8,\frac x4,\frac x2$ in succession