# Show that $8\cos(x)(\sin(2x)^2-\cos(2x)^{2})(\cos(x)^{2}- \sin(x)^2) = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

> Show that $8\cos(x)(\sin(2x)^2-\cos(2x)^{2})(\cos(x)^{2}- \sin(x)^2) =
>  1$

I am a bit confusing how to show this equation. 
I consider 
$$8\cos(x)(\sin(2x)^2-\cos(2x)^{2})(\cos(x)^{2}- \sin(x)^2) =
 1$$
$$8\cos(x)(4\sin^2(x)\cos^{2}(x)-(2\cos^2(x)-1)(\cos(x)^{2}+ \cos(x)-1) =
 1$$
$$8\cos(x)(4((1-\cos^2)\cos^{2}(x)-(2\cos^2(x)-1)(2\cos(x)^{2}-1) =
 1$$
But it's look very complicated. 
Maybe you have simply method?

EDIT:

In general I tried show that:
$$8\cos(x)(\sin^{4}(2x)-\cos^{4}(2x))= \frac{1+\tan(x)^{2}}{1-\tan(x)^{2}}$$
which implies that 
$$8\cos(x)(\sin(2x)^2-\cos(2x)^{2})(\cos(x)^{2}- \sin(x)^2) =1 $$
it's correct?

Comment: "Show that ..."? It is clearly not true for all $x$, eg take $x=0$. Do you want to know the $x$ for which it is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may write the LHS as
$$-8\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(4x)$$
and by
[Proving: $\cos A \cdot \cos 2A \cdot \cos 2^{2}A \cdot \cos 2^{3}A ... \cos 2^{n-1}A = \frac { \sin 2^n A}{ 2^n \sin A } $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/proving-cos-a-cdot-cos-2a-cdot-cos-22a-cdot-cos-23a-cos-2n)
we find that
$$-8\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(4x)=-\frac {\sin (8 x)}{\sin(x) }$$
which is NOT identically $1$.

Comment: I tried compute general formula where is reduce to your answer, $8\cos(x)(\sin^{4}(2x)-\cos^{4}(2x))= \frac{1+\tan(x)^{2}}{1-\tan(x)^{2}}$ maybe it's wrong?

Comment: @Blabla It's wrong. Take $x=\pi/4$: the LHS is bounded whereas the RHS is not bounded  because $\tan(\pi/4)=1$

Answer (score 2):

This identity cannot be true, as you can check with $x=\frac\pi2$.